# Как сделать задержку перед удалением? fadeOut-remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код element.fadeOut(1000).remove() - требуется скрыть элемент анимацией, а только затем удалить. Как это сделать? Пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeGygx

```
$(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    $('div').fadeOut(1000).remove();
  })
})
```

Понял, что анимация начинает выполняться, тут же срабатывает удаление элемента не дожидаясь окончания анимации.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что методы stop(), clearQueue() применимы только к методам анимации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `callback` функцию:

```
$(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    $('div').fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});
  });
});
```

Comment: Ну эт вы загнули все дивы удалять по окончании анимации только одного :)

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны автор все дивы и выбирает, непонятно...

Comment: @Grundy, ну так уж в вопросе был код реализован, мало ли)

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро, Только `this` не строкой передавайте :)

Comment: @Grundy, само собой, это исключительно опечатка)

Comment: Все дивы не выбираются естественно, это банальный пример.

Answer (score 3):

В функцию [jQuery.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete) можно передать второй параметр - функцию которая выполнится когда анимация закончится.

Например

```
$(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    $('div').fadeOut(1000,function(){$(this).remove();});
  })
});
```

Кроме того начиная с версии 1.6 можно использовать [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
$(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    $('div').fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function(){
        this.remove();//this - jQuery object
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Промисы – спортивно, модно, современно! Но как-то не аккуратненько )   Upvote за promise, тем не менее.

Comment: @Sergiks, а почему не аккуратненько? :-) вроде красиво так сплошные цепочки вызовов, а не колбэки :)

Comment: «букв» фактически стало больше. И если захочется ещё и `.fail()` и прочие предусмотреть, получится какой-то паровоз.

Comment: @Sergiks, хм :-) fail у анимации? :-) в любом случае, как отмечено выше: `стильно, модно, молодежно` :-D

Comment: Кнопка «я передумал», вызывающая [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), например.

Comment: @Sergiks, а она на `promise` разве влияет? что-то не уверен, надо проверить :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35545/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergiks).